# Azure SQL DW DWC Unit Comparison / Equivalent with vCores, Memory

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm trying to establish the compute equivalent with SQL DW DWC's with vCores, Memory?

Basically, I'm trying to make an argument with my employers that using the compute capacity currenty deployed on SQL DW, see image below, is so minimal that they would get better compute performance if they used a physical server or SQL DB. However, I don't know what the equivalent of DW100c is in terms of vCores, memory etc...

For example, if I wanted to purchase on physical server with the same compute power as that shown in the image, what would I need ask for in terms of vCores, IOPs, memory etc...?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't publish physical hardware specs, because we use DWUs to smooth the differences between different generations of hardware.

Any DWU scale less than 500 should really be considered a dev/test platform. You're on shared infrastructure, and the benefits of MPP for which you are paying won't be achieved.

But once you get to DWU1000c and above, you're getting huge performance gains over SMP SQL Server, Azure SQL, etc. 1000c is the lower end of performance, but I recall one exercise I was involved in last year where it was 30x faster than Azure SQL and SQL MI for the workload in question.

If you have an OLTP workload, or a mixed workload, use SMP. If you have a DW workload and your performance objectives are met by a DWU100c configuration then you are probably better off using Azure SQL, because your concurrency will be much better. At multi-terabyte scale, however, MPP will always be faster.

Comment: Hi @Ron, sorry for the delayed response. Thanks for getting back to me.